# When gitlab start,GitLab Unicorn web server is not running

Tags: ruby, gitlab

I installed gitlab using these document.: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html

When gitlab start, I get a message in the console: The GitLab Unicorn web server is not running.

It is unicorn.stderr.log:

[image: stderr.log]

I think it  occur because of shell_secret, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: my /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys is 0kb

Comment: Please post the error log as text, not an image.